# Sum of squares converges given sum does

Tags: real-analysis, summation, proof-writing

Let's say $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n=1$ and that the series converges absolutely. Is it true that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2\leq 1?$

I think it's clear how the latter converges at all, but I am unsure how to prove this upper bound.

Comment: What if $x_1=-100,$ $x_1=101$ and $x_n = 1/2^n$ for $n>1.$ Then $\sum x_n = 1$ but $\sum x_n^2 > 1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers demonstrate, this is false. However, if we impose that $x_n\ge 0$ for every $n$, then this is true. Indeed
$$
\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n^2\le\left(\sum_{n=1}^N x_n\right)^2\le\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\right)^2
$$
holds for every $N\in\mathbb{N}$, so that by taking $N\to\infty$, we obtain that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 \le \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\right)^2 = 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.  We could have $x_1=10,x_2=-9,$ and all the rest $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not.  For example, take any absolutely convergent series with sum $1$, and insert two new elements,  $2017$ and $-2017$.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Just cheat a little bit.  Let $x_1 = 2$ , $x_2 = -1$ and $x_n = 0$ otherwise.